# creation of a text file in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have an existing JSP page that displays some static text. I'd like to know how to create a file containing this static text using JSP that runs on the click of a button (such as a get or post to another jsp page with some java.io file creation logic).

Comment: Hi, Please ask the question in more explained way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this a sample creation handle it in button

```
 <%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%
 //File creation
 String strPath = "C:\\example.txt";
 File strFile = new File(strPath);
 boolean fileCreated = strFile.createNewFile();
 //File appending
 Writer objWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFile));
 objWriter.write("This is a test");
 objWriter.flush();
 objWriter.close();
%>
```

Comment: Can you write down and make the changes in your question what you have written

Comment: I hav tried ur code and den run it through browser but is it displaying error message "HTTP Status 500 -type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

"

Comment: I can not right from here ask your friends or colleagues because with out knowing where it is occurring i can not

Comment: please post the code what you have written completely and update your question so that it might give us a clear way to know why it is happening

Comment: thanks u were right.. There was some problem with tomcat dat i was using. Ur code is working for me now.. Thanks for ur help..

Comment: We can not just blame the "Servers" just because we received an HTTP 500 errors. :-) We need to look at the logs why it threw "Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@page import="java.io.File" %>

File f = new File("create.txt");
if (!f.exists())
    f.createNewFile();
```

See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) for more information on `FileWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JSP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.jsp">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click Me" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then In test.jSP , write "Dorababu" 's code

Answer (score 0):

```js
import java.io.*;

public class CmdProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd/ && D:&&cd mydir &&dir");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```